# What is this part of a chair called?

Tags: word-request

They are *not legs!* Nor are they *stands!* They are available separately (at least in India). What are they?

Objects in question are circled. What should I call them if I want to order or ask at the shop for?

> *Do you have _______ of a chair?*

[image]

Comment: What is their function?

Comment: They are sometimes called *rubber feet* (or just *feet*).

Comment: @CookieMonster they avoid friction with floors, they support the legs so that chair does not *shake!*

Comment: When asking whether a shop stocked the item, the idiomatic preposition would **for** a chair or **to** a chair.

Comment: Sometimes they're called **leg pads** or **leg caps**, but this particular chair has a tubular base rather than four legs, so a vendor might call them **chair glides** or **floor protectors**.

Comment: Feet. and 'Do you have the feet of a chair?' would make sense @Tᴚoɯɐuo no?

Comment: If I was asked *Do you have the feet of a chair?* I would reply, *No, I have the feet of a human.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [feet](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=chair%20feet). To clarify, you might say "chair feet" or "rubber feet."